# gitlab-ctl cannot execute binary

Tags: git, gitlab, centos6

We have a Linux CentOS (6.6) server which was running gitlab.  This server was installed about eighteen months ago, in another part of our network.  We migrated it across this morning, and since then, cannot start git.

```
-sh-4.1$ id
uid=502(git) gid=502(git) groups=502(git)
-sh-4.1$ gitlab-ctl start
-sh: /usr/bin/gitlab-ctl: cannot execute binary file
```

A quick google suggests that the problem is because I'm trying to run the executable on the wrong architecture, but this is not the case, since it's exactly the same architecture as it was yesterday.  And the binary is not on a network volume.

```
[root@HOSTNAME ~]# ls -lart /usr/bin/gitlab-*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 26 28 mai    2015 /usr/bin/gitlab-ctl -> /opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-ctl
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 27 28 mai    2015 /usr/bin/gitlab-rake -> /opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-rake
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 28 28 mai    2015 /usr/bin/gitlab-rails -> /opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-rails
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 30 28 mai    2015 /usr/bin/gitlab-ci-rake -> /opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-ci-rake
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 31 28 mai    2015 /usr/bin/gitlab-ci-rails -> /opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-ci-rails
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: you are executing `/usr/bin/gitlab-ctl` but showing the listing of `/opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-ctl`. Can you show how the two are related? Also, maybe `fsck` your drives to see if the binary got corrupted.

Comment: Hi.  fsck run as there was a problem rebooting.  The server now reboots normally, but still refuses to run the binary.